# Why does creating ImageViews with a loop from an ArrayList cause a memory error?

Tags: java, android

I'm working on an Android app and I've come to a section of the app where I need to get an ArrayList and create an ImageView for each String in the ArrayList. These will be displayed along the bottom of the layout and scroll horizontally.

The code I've been using for this is:

```
ArrayList<String> selectedUser = userInformation.getUserArrayList();
LinearLayout holderGUI = findViewById(R.id.holder);
Integer i = 0;
ImageView newImg;
do {
    newImg = new ImageView(this);
    Integer id = getResources().getIdentifier(selectedUser.get(i),"drawable",getPackageName());
    newImg.setImageResource(id);
    newImg.setContentDescription(selectedUser.get(i));
    newImg.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    newImg.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
    holderGUI.addView(newImg);
    i++;
} while (i < selectedUser.size());
```

This code works fine because each image file on the app matches the possible strings in the ArrayList. However, this loop only iterates three times before the app crashes with a memory allocation error. I've tried taking the block of code in the loop and just pasting it in five times to ensure that there's no issue with the loop, but I get the same result.

Is there a more efficient way to do this or is there something that I'm going wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what the array size?

Comment: @ABK In the release it will be a dynamic size that will not exceed 100 items. However, for testing purposes, I've been using a small variable size of just 5 items.

Comment: Please add logcat and at which line out of memory error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While converting String to image if string size is big then it causes OutOfMemoryError and throws an Exception so you need to handle it.

```
android:largeHeap="true"
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```

Add above lines in Manifest Application tag.

```
boolean isOutOfMemory = false;

try{
    // Your Code here.
    }catch (OutOfMemoryError ex) {
        System.gc();                // clean up largeVar data
        isOutOfMemory = true;       // flag available for use
    }
```

Add your code in try catch block.
I Hope this will work for you.

Comment: The variables in the ArrayList will only ever be 2 characters long, so I don't know if I would consider that a long String, but I will try this nevertheless since it's more of an idea that I have.